# Glyphicon is not working bootstrap-4.0.0 any alternative?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

this is the cdn of bootstrap-4.0.0 probably the latest version of bootstrap
when I include

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Glyphicon working but not in bootstrap-4 case why is there any other way to include or something else

Comment: Have you solved this question? Please, check the right answer

Answer (score 3):

According to official documentation, Bootstrap 4 is no longer supporting Glyphicons:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/extend/icons.

You can import Glyph by you own:

http://glyph.smarticons.co/

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4 no longer have glyphicon, it is dropped it new version. You can go with fontawesome, that is what bootstrap suggest for version 4.

https://fontawesome.com/